# How to create three image views for showing n number of images by using reusing image views?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, scrollview, uipagecontrol

Pagecontrol is implemented using scrollview to show multiple images on the screen. When user swipes left or right user can see next/previous images. Below is what I created image views based on the number of images. It seems like not an optimized way. Is there anyway I can create it using 2 or 3 images views and re-use them. Because, the use case is just show only one image at a time.

```
for index in 0..<pageControl.numberOfPages {
        fram.origin.x = scrollView.bounds.size.width * CGFloat(index)
        fram.size.width = scrollView.bounds.size.width
        fram.size.height = scrollView.frame.size.height
        imageView = UIImageView(frame: fram)
        imageView.setImage(images![index])
        scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
    }

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let pageNumber = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.bounds.size.width)
    pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)
}
```

Please help me how to make this optimized way without using collection views.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are actually going to end up reimplementing collection view. Any particular reason you don't want to use `UICollectionView`?

Keep in mind that it gives you bug fixes for free - courtesy of Apple engineers.

**Update** if you decide to do so, do check out WWDC video from 2014 on composite data sources, it illustrates how to avoid making the cell a data source, but to compose it with your table view instead https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/232/

**Update 2** basically you want to listen to `scrollViewDidScroll:` of the `UIScrollView.delegate` and check which subviews are outside of visible area of the `UIScrollView`, add them in the pool of views available for reuse instead of destroying, and reconfigure when a new view needs to be displayed. That's the way table or collection view works (to my understanding)

Comment: i am implementing uipagecontrol in a tableviewcell, so i didnt want to include collection view in the cell

Comment: We are actually using collection views within collection and table view cells, adding page controller as a second subview (above collection view) is quite simple, we didn't have any issues with that yet. But I understand that everyone's case is different

Comment: if i dont find solution for the above question I asked, then I will end up in going with collection view in a tableviewcell.

Comment: gotcha, I updated my answer with a link to the video that might be helpful if you do go down this path

Comment: updated with a high level solution using scroll view, hope this helps